# pthread_cond_wait unlocks mutex attached with it. source code?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I know pthread_cond_wait unlocks the mutex attached with it. What i would like to locate is the source code of pthread_cond_wait, and to locate unlocking the mutex code.  Kindly bare if the question is silly. :).  Which library do i have to download and check. I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pthread_cond_*` functions and `pthread_mutex_*` functions are part of NPTL which is now part of `glibc` on any modern Linux machine. The latest version is `glibc-2.11.1` and you can find the source code on the [GNU glibc download site](ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/glibc/releases/).

Comment: It should be noted that this implementation has a number of serious unaddressed bugs, many of which are connected to: http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13165

Comment: @R.. Wow, thanks for the link. That's very unfortunate, those are clear indications of an incorrect condvar implementation.

Comment: Yeah. It all seems to stem from some black magic they're performing to try to account for the number of wakes, apparently in an effort to eliminate all spurious wakes. However, I've run the test case from the bug report against both the NPTL condvar implementation and my own implementation that doesn't use any such hacks, and haven't been able to get any spurious wakes with either, so my conclusion so far is that their efforts to prevent spurious wakes are unnecessary and (due to the bugs) simply harmful...

Comment: Minimizing spurious wakeups is good. Correctness, however, is essential.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative would be the OpenSolaris [source](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/lib/libc/port/threads/synch.c); granted if you're interested in the linux, i.e. glibc, @David Schwartz's answer might be more "accurate".

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't exactly the answer to your question, the important aspect of how the mutex unlock happens is that it must be done **after** the condition variable structure is updated to reflect that a waiter is present. This is what the standard means when it says the function "atomically" unlocks the mutex and waits. Otherwise, the same race condition would exist as if you just unlocked the mutex yourself before calling `pthread_cond_wait`: Another thread could get the mutex and modify the state on which the predicate depends after you checked the predicate (and found it false) but before you called `pthread_cond_wait`. You would then miss the signal and remain waiting on the cond var, perhaps forever.